# Is there any way to manipulate the existing preFilters in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()` functions allows to add preFilters to the built-in ones, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get access to the internal jQuery preFilters. In jQuery 1.11.1 I see there is a private `preFilters` object declared in line 8568, but I don't see a method to return or manipulate this.

I've added my preFilter already, but some of the existing preFilters (namely for `dataType = 'script'`) are messing with it. Plus, I want to be able to dynamically add/remove/re-arrange preFilters at runtime.

This is a codepen illustrating the idea: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Yqzwqp

When you check the checkbox, all GET calls are automatically converted to POST. When you uncheck it, they go back to normal.
The only shorthand method that doesn't respect that is `$.getScript()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()`?

Comment: [$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {})](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/)

Comment: Yes, sorry, will edit the original post.

Comment: What is your issue with `dataType = 'script'`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I added a preFilter which redirects all requests to one URL and converts them all to POST, for a REST service. But $.getScript() ignores it and keeps being sent as GET, because there is one preFilter already defined for datatype 'script' (line 9745 in jQuery 1.11.1)

Comment: Why would `$.getScript` need to use POST? it's  script request which are GET by default. Post some code if you want help

Comment: _"I added a preFilter which redirects all requests to one URL and converts them all to POST"_ If all requests are converted to `POST` requests , could you substitute using `$.post()` for `$.getScript()` ?

Comment: Due to the nature of how works `$.getScript()`, i don't think you can use a POST method. Instead use `$.post()` and handle yourself the response to add to document the relevant script

Comment: There is no reason why a POST request cannot return a script. I want all AJAX calls to be POSTed to one URL, and since `$.getScript()` internally uses `$.ajax()` the only thing that's blocking me is this internal, pre-defined jQuery preFilter that I mentioned above. It works for all other jQuery shorthand methods, including `$.get()`.

Comment: I will try to post a jsfiddle later to explain better.

Comment: It just looks like you need to set in ajaxPrefilter `if (options.dataType === "script") {
    options.type = "POST";
    options.crossDomain = false;
  }`  BUT you would have better to use another method than `$.getScript()` and that's said, wouldn't work if script set on another domain which i guess it is your case here

Comment: @A.Wolff indeed, it's my case and it doesn't work, I'm already setting `options.type = "POST"` for all calls. It is still ignored by `$.getScript()`. My goal is to create an extension that when plugged into existing code will require no changes to whatever jQuery ajax code is there. So, if there's somewhere a `$.getScript()` it will transparently work.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets Ok, that makes sense then

Comment: What is expected `dataType` response from `POST` ?

Comment: Question should be updated with all relevant information and some code

Comment: As I said above, I will try to upload a jsfiddle later. Hopefully it will clarify the situation.

Comment: Codepen added as promised.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets Have you resolved Question ?

Comment: No, if I did I would post it here. I gave up trying. It looks like the preFilter mechanism in jQuery is so deeply integrated that there is no way to remove the default internal preFilters for scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `beforeSend` option of `$.ajaxSetup()` `.abort()`, `.ajaxError()` to handle errors

```
$.ajaxSetup({    
  beforeSend: function(jqxhr, settings) {
    if (settings.type === "GET" && settings.dataType === "script") {
      // abort `$.getScript()`
      jqxhr.abort();
      // convert `type` to `POST`
      settings.type = "POST";
      // convert `dataType` to expected response from `POST`
      settings.dataType = "json";
      settings.cache = false;
      // remove query string from , replace `url`
      settings.url = "script2.js"; /* settings.url.replace(/\?.*$/, ""); */
      console.log("beforeSend", settings);
      // use updated `settings` object
      $.ajax(settings)
    }
  },
  complete: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    console.log("complete", data)
  }
});

$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, errorThrown) {
  // handle aborted `$.getScript()` requests
  console.log("err", event, jqxhr, settings, errorThrown)
});
// `request` should be converted into `$.ajax({type:"POST"})`
var request = $.getScript("script1.js");
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Q9PmTVnO4LoWvvjmIBLs?p=preview

Comment: I was trying to avoid using `$.ajaxSetup()` to override the `beforeSend` method, because among other things, it violates my last request in the original post. I want to be able to disable it dynamically. I suppose I could store a reference to the original `beforeSend` and restore it. If I don't manage to do it with `$.ajaxPrefilter` I will probably go this way. Thanks

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets _"it violates my last request in the original post"_ ? Can you describe how it violates requirement at OP ? Can you include `js` you have tried using `$.ajaxPrefilter()` at Question ?

Comment: Please read my comments above, I said I will post a jsfiddle later.

Comment: Codepen added as promised.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets Have you tried to incorporate `js` at post at codepen ? Note, using `$.Callbacks('unique');` should allow same function to be added to list at most once . Note certain what expected result at codepen is ?

Comment: Not certain what your question is about either. If you mean trying to incorporate your JS code, I did, but it didn't work, because I need the returned datatype to still be `script`, not `json`, as in your example. Plus, as I said above, my original question was about jQuery prefilters, not modifying `beforeSend`. If you can incorporate your JS on my codepen and make it work, that would be great! :)

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets What is the purpose of converting `$.getScript()` to a `POST` request ? Still not sure what you are trying to achieve ? Can you clarify what requirement is ?

Comment: I wrote it in the comments above, we need to redirect all AJAX requests to a REST API.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets _"If you mean trying to incorporate your JS code, I did, but it didn't work, because I need the returned datatype to still be script, not json, as in your example"_ Is response from REST API `js` that should be called ? Can you describe "it didn't work" ?

Comment: Yes, of course it's "js that should be called", it's a script, it has to behave exactly like a script returned from the normal `$.getScript()`.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets _"we need to redirect all AJAX requests to a REST API."_ a) Initial `url` is changed ? b) New `url` is set , which returns a `script` ? c) The client is not supposed to be aware of `url` to their initial `$.ajax()` request being changed ? d) Execute the `script` as if initial `$.ajax()` request did not actually fetch and execute `script` ?

Comment: I don't see how any of this is relevant to my initial question, but (a) the URL may be changed (the client may ask for a relative URL which will be transformed to point to the REST API), (b) yes (c) the client is of course aware, we're building the application (d) `eval`uate the script the same way `$.getScript()` does, in other words, let the jQuery internals do whatever they do normally. I don't understand what is not clear about it.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets Still not able to fully gather what you are attempting to achieve, here. Perhaps you should start a bounty for the Question ?

Comment: I don't see how a bounty is going to help clarify things for you, but anyway, thank you for your effort.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets Not a bounty for this user, as still not able to gather why attempting to convert `$.getScript()` to `POST` , or use `beforeSend` , if not at `$.ajaxSetup()` , at individual `$.ajax()` call; but for others users that may better understand what you are trying  to accomplish and able to compose `js` to meet requirements